# Return PDF from Published Apps Script Webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am new to apps script.
I have a container bound script deployed as web app.

What I want to accomplish is call the web app url with some parameters which write values to a cell in the sheet. The other cell values are calculated based on supplied value.

When I call the url, the script should return PDF format of the sheet.

I found many examples where PDF file is saved to Drive and Link is returned. But I am not able to accomplish this seemingly simple task.

This is what I have tried
But I get this error
**Exception: Converting from application/pdf to text/html is not supported. (line 4, file "Code")**

```
function doGet(e) {

//Script part that writes value to cell
//...
//...
//...

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<sheet url>/export?format=pdf&gid=<sheet gid>');
  var blob = response.getBlob();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(blob);
}
```

Comment: *call the web app url* Called from a browser or some  terminal or automated utility like curl?

Comment: The blob you provide in `createHtmlOutput` should contain HTML content (see [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutput(BlobSource))). In this case, you might want to embed this PDF in your HTML, and probably save the PDF to Drive. Do you think this workaround would be appropriate for your situation?

Comment: @TheMaster I want to use curl like utility

Comment: @lamblichus I do not want to store PDF. Is it possible to remove PDF from Drive as soon as downloaded?

Comment: Don't think it is possible to send blob. But why not just send  the export link `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<sheet url>/export?format=pdf&gid=<sheet gid>'`? Curl can download it